# phpThumb() com CakePHP + erro

Tags: php, cakephp, thumbnail

Opá,

Estou com problema em carregar as imagens onde passam pela função phpThumb(), retornando o erro conforme a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me dar um help? Local está funcionando...
Servidor com PHP Versão 5.4.*
Suporte á ImageMagick e GD ( Requisitado )
Permissões nas pastas ok...

O que pode estar ocorrendo este problema?
Link: http://kymerasemijoias.com.br

Comment: Você pode postar o trecho do código que gera essas imagens?